# how to select all documents from mongodb where one field does not equal a certain value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, database

I am looking to select all documents thats field 'author' does not equal a certain username from my mongodb table called Posts.

so far i tried

```
Posts.find( { author: { $not: 'username' } } );
```

that didn't work, it returned everything

any ideas?

Comment: if i run on console `Posts.find( { author: { $not: "molleman" } } ).fetch();` it returns `[]`, thats what you want not? ... `Posts.find( { author: { $not: "molleman"} } ).count();` return 0 and  `Posts.find().count();` return 42

Comment: The `$not` operator doesn't take a string as input.

Comment: i just run it on console, to show it works, it should be a problem on the input value, maybe molleman its not passing a correct value or something

Answer (score 4):

Use the [**$ne**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne) operator, if the input is a string.

```
Posts.find( { author: { $ne: 'username' } } );
```

The [**$not**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) operator takes an `expression` or a `regex` as input and performs a logical not on the output in case of expressions.

> $not performs a logical NOT operation on the specified
>   `<operator-expression>` and selects the documents that do not match the
>   `<operator-expression>`. This includes documents that do not contain the
>   field.

```
Syntax: { field: { $not: { <operator-expression> } } }
```

You could pass a `regex` to the `$not` operator this way:

```
var reg = new RegExp('username');
Posts.find( { author: { $not: reg } } );
```

Comment: just tried that also, dosnt work, check out http://www.themmatrends.com if you want, you can test it in the browser console ....

Comment: @molleman - Can you update your question with the sample document in the collection and the correct input passed. There may be something else missing in your code.